# Including 32- and 64-bit merge modules in one WiX installer

Tags: module, merge, wix, anycpu

I'm writing merge modules for a project I'm working on.

I build two merge modules, one for 32-bit and one for 64-bit. I want to include them in a WiX installer but it tells me I can't:
error LGHT0345: 'installer\bin\x64\Release\en-us\myproject.msm' is a 64-bit merge module but the product consuming it is 32-bit. 32-bit products can consume only 32-bit merge modules.

Is there a way to make a dual CPU project so I can include both?

WiX version is 3.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Installer doesn't support multi-platform packages. If you need to write to the 64-bit portion of the file system or registry, you need a 64-bit package.

Comment: The merge modules for the Visual Studio runtimes seem to be able to pull it off somehow, why can't I? For example one called Microsoft_VC90_CRT_x86_x64.msm.

Comment: A 64-bit package can include both 32-bit and 64-bit components. A 32-bit package can include only 32-bit components.

Comment: I've included the file mentioned above in a 32-bit installer. If I open it (the VC redist msm) in orca it doesn't specify which platform it's for. Seems like it's not specified.

Comment: Yes, it's also slightly "special" in that even though it has 64-bit files, they're side-by-side assemblies. Those are different than files that go into Program Files, for example.